# PLS (Partial Least Squares) deflation and graphics

Tags: latent-variable, partial-least-squares

I have been working with pls for a little while now. I have a question in terms of the deflation of both the $X$ and $Y$ matrices.
In the literature I have found different methods over which deflation is carried out, including
 $X_{n+1}=X_n - t_np_n$
 $Y_{n+1}=Y_n - t_nc_n$
with $tn$ being the $n^{th}$ score of $X$, $p_n$ the $n^{th}$ loading vector of $X$ and $c_n$ the $n^{th}$ weight vector of $Y$  (as found in [here](https://learnche.org/pid/latent-variable-modelling/projection-to-latent-structures/how-the-pls-model-is-calculated)).

$X_{n+1} = X_n - t_nw_n$
$Y_{n+1} = Y_n - u_nc_n$
with $w_n$ the $n^{th}$ weight vector of $X$ and $u_n$ the $n^{th}$ score of $Y$ (as found in [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~kee/pls.pdf))

Both methods yield different results. From results I have obtained, $U$ and $T$ scores are more similar in the second case but the explained variance % is greater for the first case. Which (if any) is more correct? Is it also correct to state that, the more similar $U$ and $T$, the more sense it makes to graph and compare in weights for $X$ and $Y$ together? As in the example:
[image]

Because the $T$ and $U$ scores (points in the graph) are very similar, am I able to state that the $F$,$C$ and $B$,$E$ are correlated?

Comment: There are many many different flavours of PLS with different deflation schemes. If you just say "PLS", it's not clear what exactly you are referring to. See http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~zwp/teach/Reg/overview_pls.pdf, Section 2.1.

Comment: @amoeba Thank you for the link, I found it really helpful. Still, regardless of which mode I would chose to implement, is the last question of my answer correct?

Comment: Probably yes, but if you just want to know if F and C are correlated, then you can simply compute the correlation between them, no?

Comment: Surely, but imagine if the $T$ and $U$ scores are not similar at all - then it would not make sense to check this correlation right?